# How can you edit text in draw.io shapes?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I know how to label shapes in [draw.io](https://draw.io) by simply clicking on the shape and then typing, but how can I go back and easily edit These Labels without first deleting and recreating the entire text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double click on the shape to start editing with the label intact.

Answer (score 4):

Usually double-clicking the text portion of the shape lets you edit it.  Some of the shapes don't work this well and tend to just give you a handle to reposition the text instead (e.g. the UML Diagram Generalization arrow).  If that's the case, right click on the shape and select edit.  It should select the text portion for editing.

Answer (score 2):

For arrows with text the following worked for me:

1. Left-click the arrow

   - cursor turns into the "move" icon
2. double-click the "move" icon

   - your text will become selected and you can re-type/edit your text

Comment: this is not the correct answer but suite my case. the goal is to edit the existing label (default) not creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Left-click on the property(e.g. a message arrow in UML);
2. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then you can edit the text.

This works for me.

Comment: Thanks! since double-click does not work anymore, F2 and/or enter was too obvious that I did not try it and looked for other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

To make everything editable, go:

1. Edit -> Select All
2. Edit -> Lock/Unlock

Answer (score 1):

On arrow **objects** there's a small handle you can double-click to edit the text. The other answers here didn't seem to work for arrows.

Comment: This is the only thing (pressing enter) worked consistently for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select the property you want to rename, then on the left side pane in **Style** at the bottom property value is given. [image: Editable checkbox tick]

click on editable checkbox as shown in picture. This may help you to edit the text.